# I make a android browser .But it doesn't support youtube video and other video also .Only sound play when i play the video and the video is black

Tags: android, video, browser, webview

I make a android browser .But it doesn't support youtube video and other video also .Only sound play when i play the video and the video is black. so i need the solution of this problem .Thanks in advance .

This is my code

```
package com.example.ashraful.userinterface;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class Main2Activity extends Activity {

WebView web1;
EditText ed1;
Button bt1;
String Address;
String add;
ProgressBar pbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2); 
    web1 = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    ed1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    bt1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    pbar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    pbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Address = "http://" + ed1.getText().toString();
            WebSettings webSetting = web1.getSettings();
            webSetting.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            webSetting.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webSetting.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);


            web1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

            web1.loadUrl(Address);

        }
    });
}

public class WebViewClient extends android.webkit.WebViewClient
{
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        pbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ed1.setText(""); // clear
        ed1.setText(view.getUrl());

        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        pbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && web1.canGoBack()) {
        web1.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, MainActivity.class);
    myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);// clear back stack
    startActivity(myIntent);

    finish();
    return;
}

}
```

And This is XML code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.ashraful.userinterface.Main2Activity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="GO"
    android:layout_width="45dp" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/view12"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="3dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="#3bbdfa" />

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Type Your URL Here"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I too faced this error.. In my app, network strength is low. so video is not played. It need high speed internet connection.

Comment: Why do you need a browser for that?

Comment: @Rotwang I am  making  a browser and that does not support youtube video and other html 5 video .so" why i need a browser for that?" what kind of question is that?

Comment: @Shunmugapriya I am using  6 mbps internet speed ..That speed is not enough for that

Comment: You don't need a browser, if you only want to display videos fetched from the internet.

Comment: @Rotwang I don't want to display video only . I want to do all thing a browser can do .But for making this i face a problem that is when i go to youtube via my browser the video can't be displayed only i heard the audio.